# Appending to Response::json() from App::after after returning from my controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have route, then it will call function from my controller, in my controller, I am returning using `return Response::json(array);` , now, I have `App::after` which i want to append something to the current Response returned by my controller, is there any way to get the current response inside `App::after` filter?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i can get the current response by simply using:

```
$return = json_decode($response->getContent());
$return->hasLogout = true; // Appended new response data
$response->setContent(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: Note that you can use `getData()` and `setData()` instead of `getContent()` and `setContent()`. This way it will do the JSON conversion for you.